# CSS class selector issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why doesn't this work? I'm new to CSS, and I don't know why the following won't work.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="tabnav">
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="index2.html">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="index3.html">Tab Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="index4.html">Tab Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul #tabnav li.selected { 
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there's no element with id `tabnav` as *child* of an `ul` element.

Either remove the `ul`

```
#tabnav li.selected { 
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

or attach it to the `ul`

```
ul#tabnav li.selected { 
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: "no element with id `tabnav` as a *descendant* (at any level) of `ul`.</nitpick>

Comment: @Bolt: I didn't mean to say that it's a *direct* child, but just a child. *Descendant* is maybe indeed a better word choice.

Comment: Yeah I know. After all, all grandchildren are children of their own parents who are themselves children of their own parents and \*head explodes\*

Answer (score 0):

Addition to answer above: 
I dont know how good css handles background-color: #f00; The hexadecimal value should be six decimals long. (two first representing Red, Next blue and last green)

```
background-color:#FF0000;
```

Comment: Three-digit hex values are valid CSS, they just get doubled to their six-digit values, so `#rgb` becomes `#rrggbb` just as you say.

Comment: ok, thank you for clearing that up. I believe however that it is both prettier and safer using all six digits :)

Comment: Prettier maybe, but equally safe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
#nav #tabnav li.selected {
    background-color: #f00;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Since ID's are supposed to be unique, it's unnecessary to put `#nav` in front. There's only one of `#tabnav` anyway.